# how to use create scrollable body with default tab bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, tabs, tabbar

i want to create page using tab bar and also singlechildscrollview in flutter, and i still dont get any solution for it. i want to have an icon and text for tab description so i guess i cant use tabs.map as string only and here is my code. and i've been try to add refractor the body with singlechildscrollview and everything disappear

```
bottom: const TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.blue, //<-- selected text color
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey, //<-- Unselected text
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.mail,
                        // color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Inbox",
                        // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.inbox,
                        // color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Disposisi",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          // color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: const TabBarView(
            children: [
              listBerita(),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            ],
          )),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rhjc.jpg)
i was expecting that my data that imported from listBerita() can be scrolled

Comment: Can you include sample data for `listBerita`

Comment: Can you try to wrap your returned widget with SingleChildScrollView of listBerita

Answer (score 0):

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Appbar'),
      bottom: const TabBar(
              labelColor: Colors.blue, //<-- selected text color
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey, //<-- Unselected text
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.mail,
                        // color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Inbox",
                        // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 14),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Tab(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.inbox,
                        // color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Disposisi",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          // color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
    body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              listBerita(),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            ],
          ),
  ),
);

Widget listBerita(){
  return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                title: Text("List item $index"));
          });
}
```